# Android Image Scaling Bigger than Screen

Tags: android, image, imageview, scale, scaletransform

We have an app which is using some images bigger than existing products screens. We have two test device for android applications. Also we have emaulators using Android 4.3 and 4.2.2 .

Samsung Galaxy S3 / Android 4.1.2
Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1/ Android 4.0.4

Each device,we tried to implement our app.The problem is our image has 1237x1602 pixels size but the screen size is 720x1230 for Samsung Galaxy S3 and 800x1280 pixels. That is why our image displayed cropped horizantally and vertically. We want to put whole image and translate it. We create layout programmatically and give the biggest Rect possible but nothing solved.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks,

MK

Comment: Add some of your code so that we can understand more clear.

Comment: @sandeep this is not about a code problem. the devices automatically crop the big image according to screens resolution. I need to create the whole image and translate it. I create layout programmatically and give the biggest Rect possible but nothing solved.

Comment: Did you try resizing image as per needs ?

Comment: I suggest you not to crop our image, get the screen size first then scale down the bitmap to the screen size, wich will make the image small without cropping it.http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Comment: My suggestion is, get screen size using display metrics and then scale down the image according to the screen size. I asked the code so that we can get the clear understanding of your applying of the image to the view. Showing some of your code can help us to help you more.

Comment: @Jay I am using any kind of scaletype for imageview but I do not want to crop or get smaller image. My image has 1237x1602 pixels. I just want to put that image and translate it on the screen without any cropped part.

Comment: @sandeep My app is really complicated and I cannot put all the code here just say that I create a RelativeLayout programatically and put some small images and I want to and another image in front of them which has 1237x1602 pixels. I hope I can explained it properly sorry about lack of information...

Answer (score 0):

Ok you can try this, as per your comments you do not want to crop image so try creating Matrix of your image and resizing it. It **wont** crop your image.

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
m.postscale(/*give your scaling here as per requirement*/);
imageView.setImageMatrix(m);
```

Try it out as it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

before that set ImageView height and width as per you will need. I think your problem will be solved.

Try and give feedback.